# Issue with Asynctask and progressdialog?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask, progress-bar, progressdialog

i am a noob to android and I am trying to show a progressdialog during OnCreate method after my splashscreen.  Currently, after my splashscreen, the screen is black for about 5 seconds then the layout appears.  I am using an Asynctask to do my background operations, so I don't understand why the progressdialog doesn't appear instead of the 5 seconds of black when the app is initializing.  This only happens with Android 3.0 and lower.  All subsequent sdk releases show the progressdialog properly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //wakelock
    PowerManager pM = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wL = pM.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "Screen Dim");
    wL.acquire();


    LoadingData dataLoaded = new LoadingData();
    dataLoaded.execute("");

    ---code for UI Thread---

    }//--End onCreate

private class LoadingData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) {
        try {
            //TWITTER API CODE HERE

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+ e.toString());
            }
            publishProgress(33);

            //DOWNLOADING IMAGES CODE HERE
            try{

            }catch(Exception e){

            } 
            publishProgress(66);

            //FOREX RATES CODE HERE
            try {

        }catch(JSONException e)        {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error acquiring forex data "+e.toString());
        }
        publishProgress(100);


        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog (GoldandSilverCoinCalculatorActivity.this);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading... please wait");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setMax(100);
        dialog.setProgress(0);
        dialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        dialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
    } 

    @Override       
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {       
        super.onPostExecute(result);       
        dialog.dismiss();

       }


}
```

----EDIT----
My OnResume and OnPause Methods

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    compass.disableCompass();
    super.onPause();
    wL.release();
    lm.removeUpdates(this);
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    compass.enableCompass();
    super.onResume();
    wL.acquire();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(towers, 500, 1, this);
}
```

Comment: What's in the ---code for UI Thread--- ??
Your Dialog will NOT show until the entire OnCreate is done. So there might be something taking a long time in your UI initialization

Comment: That's where I instantiate my button's, spinners, textviews, & editexts for my layout.

Comment: Make sure that there is no bitmap manipulation or processing intensive code in your onCreate/onStart/onResume.

Comment: Please check my edit.  I just posted my onPause and OnResume.  Could these operations be blocking my UI thread?

Comment: Nothing in this code is blocking! I don't know why this is happening!
I suggest logging your code to make sure that there's nothing blocking your onCreate

Comment: Do you ever discover the solution to this? I'm getting the same issue and would like to know. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To show a progress dialog in AsyncTask use onPreExecute() method of AsyncTask

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);   // if true, it enables to dismiss dialog with back button
        pDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm still getting the 5 seconds of black screen.

Comment: I think the problem is with '//wakelock' Please try to comment all the related to it lines and follow my solution. This should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Comment one by one all of your lines of codes ... to see what takes 5s

I think your problem is that the lines :

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

should be at the top of your onCreate and not after acquiring the wake lock

Comment: I just tried reordering the lines like you suggested with no luck.  So I guess i will have comment my lines one by one.